# PrimeNg persist column resize state in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I 'm try to implement order,toggle,resize (Fit Mode) feture on primeng table so far  order and toggle update `selectedColumns` array so if I save the current value of it  I manage to save current user setting like toggle,order.

my problem with resize primeng doesn't give any information about the new value of columns after resize so I couldn't find any way to get the current state of resize and save it like order and toggle.

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-order-resize-toggle)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Primeng 7](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/304) introduce a `state` feature for TurboTable (p-table) component,
to setup `state` simple set stateStorage property to local along with the state key;

```
<p-table [columns]="selectedColumns" stateStorage="local" stateKey="state01" 
            [value]="carsData" [reorderableColumns]="true" [resizableColumns]="true">
....
</p-table>
```

Currently supported features that can be stateful are;

- page
- sort
- filter
- selection
- column resize
- column reorder
- row expansion

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53280266)

[**primeng-table-state**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/state)

Comment: yes, it is persisting filters, pagination and sorting but not persisting a expanded rows. is there any other option for it?